# Convert RDD to JSON Object

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I have an RDD of type RDD[(String, List[String])].

Example:

```
(FRUIT, List(Apple,Banana,Mango))
(VEGETABLE, List(Potato,Tomato))
```

I want to convert the above output to json object like below.

```
{
  "categories": [
    {
      "name": "FRUIT",
      "nodes": [
        {
          "name": "Apple",
          "isInTopList": false
        },
        {
          "name": "Banana",
          "isInTopList": false
        },
        {
          "name": "Mango",
          "isInTopList": false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "VEGETABLE",
      "nodes": [
        {
          "name": "POTATO",
          "isInTopList": false
        },
        {
          "name": "TOMATO",
          "isInTopList": false
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Please suggest the best possible way to do it.

NOTE: `"isInTopList": false` is always constant and has to be there with every item in the jsonobject.

Comment: Use any libraray like Play, Lift or Jakson

Comment: If there is no risk of line breaks or such in the input, it's probably faster to create the output with a simple string substitution. If you cannot make assumptions about the input, use a library.

Comment: You can create whatever you want when running in local, but when you get to run in actual clusters, write operations to desired locations are only possible through Spark functions, and Spark doesn't allow directly saving to JSON

Answer (score 6):

First I used the following code to reproduce the scenario that you mentioned:

```
val sampleArray = Array(
("FRUIT", List("Apple", "Banana", "Mango")),
("VEGETABLE", List("Potato", "Tomato")))

val sampleRdd = sc.parallelize(sampleArray)
sampleRdd.foreach(println) // Printing the result
```

Now, I am using [json4s](http://json4s.org/) Scala library to convert this RDD into the JSON structure that you requested:

```
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._
import org.json4s.JsonDSL.WithDouble._

val json = "categories" -> sampleRdd.collect().toList.map{
case (name, nodes) =>
  ("name", name) ~
  ("nodes", nodes.map{
    name => ("name", name)
  })
}

println(compact(render(json))) // Printing the rendered JSON
```

The result is:

```
{"categories":[{"name":"FRUIT","nodes":[{"name":"Apple"},{"name":"Banana"},{"name":"Mango"}]},{"name":"VEGETABLE","nodes":[{"name":"Potato"},{"name":"Tomato"}]}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want a single JSON for you entire RDD, I would start by doing `Rdd.collect`. Be careful that your set fits in memory, as this will move the data back to the driver.

To get the json, just use a library to traverse your objects. I like Json4s due to its simple internal structure and practical, clean operators. Here is a sample from their website that shows how to traverse nested structures (in particular, lists):

```
object JsonExample extends App {
  import org.json4s._
  import org.json4s.JsonDSL._
  import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

  case class Winner(id: Long, numbers: List[Int])
  case class Lotto(id: Long, winningNumbers: List[Int], winners: List[Winner], drawDate: Option[java.util.Date])

  val winners = List(Winner(23, List(2, 45, 34, 23, 3, 5)), Winner(54, List(52, 3, 12, 11, 18, 22)))
  val lotto = Lotto(5, List(2, 45, 34, 23, 7, 5, 3), winners, None)

  val json =
    ("lotto" ->
      ("lotto-id" -> lotto.id) ~
      ("winning-numbers" -> lotto.winningNumbers) ~
      ("draw-date" -> lotto.drawDate.map(_.toString)) ~
      ("winners" ->
        lotto.winners.map { w =>
          (("winner-id" -> w.id) ~
           ("numbers" -> w.numbers))}))

  println(compact(render(json)))
}
```

Comment: Hello Daniel, can I iterate this method in the dataframe to convert my data into a json object?