# PySpark: spit out single file when writing instead of multiple part files

Tags: python, amazon-s3, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a way to prevent PySpark from creating several small files when writing a DataFrame to JSON file?

If I run:

```
 df.write.format('json').save('myfile.json')
```

or

```
df1.write.json('myfile.json')
```

it creates the folder named `myfile` and within it I find several small files named `part-***`, the HDFS way. Is it by any means possible to have it spit out a single file instead?

Comment: No, unless you want to `coalesce(1)` (and you really should avoid that). Why do you need this?

Comment: I need to read the file from another Python, non pyspark, script

Comment: If the end dataset is truly very small, then I see nothing wrong with `coalesce(1)`. However, you do need to be careful with this as it will pull all the data into the driver.

Comment: @zero323 I need to write on a AWS S3 bucket

Comment: @KatyaHandler `coalesce` doesn't pull anything to the driver (it is not `collect`). In general (ignoring parallelism) it introduces a serious bottleneck since data has to be fetched to a single worker and send from a single worker. Not to mention it can fail for multiple reasons including different 2GB limits.

Comment: @martina If you have a code that can read from S3 does it really matter (assuming the number is low enough so you don't hit different S3 issues) if you read a single file or a few. You can simply `chain` the reads.

Comment: @zero323 Would I have the same situation if I transformed the PySpark DataFrame to a Pandas one?

Comment: `toPandas` is just a `collect` with some shiny additions. If you can accept `collect` you can accept `toPandas`. If not... You're back to the square one. If data is to be processed locally then it can a better choice than gathering, pushing and loading back.

Comment: If you need the data to be one file, you should `collect` them. Otherwise, you should accept the Hadoop way. That's the point of using a distributed computing environment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, the answer to your exact question is `coalesce` function. But as already mentioned it is not efficient at all as it will force one worker to fetch all data and write it sequentially.

```
df.coalesce(1).write.format('json').save('myfile.json')
```

P.S. Btw, the result file is not a valid json file. It is a file with a json object per line.

Comment: About the non-validity of the JSON, this happens in any case, even when spitting out several files.

Comment: @martina, yep. It is confusing sometimes to see `.json` extension and no valid json file inside :D

Comment: for me, this line created directory named `myfile.json` with one part file inside (using spark 2.4)

Answer (score 0):

This was a better solution for me.

`rdd.map(json.dumps)
    .saveAsTextFile(json_lines_file_name)`

Comment: remember you do need to concat the parts files after it is produced. http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=saveastextfile#pyspark.RDD.saveAsTextFile

Answer (score -2):

`df1.rdd.repartition(1).write.json('myfile.json')`

Would be nice, but isn't available. Check this related question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33311467/2843520

Comment: `df.coalesce(1).write.json('myfile.json')` works fine