# pyspark dataframe to HDFS saving too many files

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs, apache-spark-sql

I'm aggregating data and would like to save the results in HDFS. My final results are only 6 rows and 2 columns worth of data. However, when I save it to HDFS it saves over 200 files; which I'm assuming is some type of pre-processing. When I look in the files they are also all just blank.

```
results = aggregate.filter(aggregate["count"] > 2500)

results.show()
+--------------+-----+
|          c_ip|count|
+--------------+-----+
| 198.51.100.61| 2619|
|  203.0.113.33| 2635|
|198.51.100.211| 2668|
|198.51.100.121| 2723|
|198.51.100.176| 2518|
| 198.51.100.16| 2546|
+--------------+-----+

results.write.format("csv").save("/sparkcourse/results")
```

How do I save to HDFS so I get one file with these results? Obviously this data fits in one file.

The other thing I tried was using .collect() but then it turned my data into a list and couldn't get anything into HDFS with that option.

```
results = aggregate.filter(aggregate["count"] > 2500).collect()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Spark* **repartitions data into 200 partitions whenever there is a shuffle** in the processing. **Shuffling occurs whenever there is need of transfering data from one node to another or between executors**. So when you save the dataframe (which already has 200 partitions) 200 files are created for each partitions and some metadata files are written.

So the solution to your problem is to use `coalesce(1)` function so that one worker node to write to output path as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36210670/5880706)

```
results.coalesce(1).write.format("csv").save("/sparkcourse/results")
```

Or you can use `repartition(1)` as

```
results.repartition(1).write.format("csv").save("/sparkcourse/results")
```

Comment: Great explanation! I kind of mixed up .collect() with .coalesce and .repartition(1). I though that when I did .collect() it collected everything to one node but it just ended up making my results into a list.

Comment: collect() accumulates all data in the driver node as a collection.