# How can write files with repartition with structured streaming's writestream?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I have a structured streaming code that reads data from Kafka and dumps to HDFS. While dumping the data, I partition the data on the basis of three columns. The problem I am facing is many small files being generated during a batch. I want to generate only one file during a batch in each partitionBy. I am not sure how can I apply repartition in this scenario as it doesn't seem to work.

```
        query = df.selectExpr("CAST(value as STRING)") \
                .repartition(1) \
                .writeStream.partitionBy('host', 'dt', 'h') \ ==> repartition(1) is not working here
                .format("parquet") \
                .outputMode("append") \
                .option("checkpointLocation", self.checkpoint_location) \
                .option('path', self.hdfs_path) \
                .option('failOnDataLoss', 'false') \
                .option("startingOffset", "earliest") \
                .trigger(processingTime='2 seconds').start()
```

I don't want to write another cleanup job that reads the data from the path, repartitions it and stores the data with the desired number of files in each partition.

Comment: Can you let us know what is your batch interval, the number of records that you receive for the particular batch ?

Comment: Batch interval is 10 minutes & the number of records per batch is around 10 million

Comment: 10 Million is a good amount of records, then you have to reconsider your partitionBy columns, as if those three columns are of high cardinality it will make small files. Try to check how many records are there for each partition group which can give you some idea why the Spark is writing smaller files

Comment: Here is a solution
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36210670/3021747)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run some test using repartition and it seems to work for me.
I created a test Kafka topic and it has data in string format `id-value`. Then in streaming code  I split `value` on `-` and write data with `partitionBy('id')` to mimic your code behavior. I am using kafka broker 0.10 and spark version 2.4.3.

See below code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, split
df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
  .option("subscribe", "partitionTestTopic") \
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
  .load()
```

Use `repartition(1)`:

```
df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)") \
  .withColumn('id', split(col('value'), '-').getItem(0)) \
  .repartition(1) \
  .writeStream.partitionBy('id') \
  .format("parquet") \
  .outputMode("append") \
  .option('path', 'test-1/data') \
  .option("checkpointLocation", "test-1/checkpoint") \
  .trigger(processingTime='20 seconds') \
  .start()
```

Output:

```
├── id=1
│   └── part-00000-9812bd07-3c0f-442e-a80c-5c09553f20e8.c000.snappy.parquet
├── id=2
│   └── part-00000-522e99b6-3900-4702-baf7-2c55819b775c.c000.snappy.parquet
├── id=3
│   └── part-00000-5ed9bef0-4941-451f-884e-8e94a351323f.c000.snappy.parquet
```

Use `repartition(3)`:

```py
df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)") \
  .withColumn('id', split(col('value'), '-').getItem(0)) \
  .repartition(3) \
  .writeStream.partitionBy('id') \
  .format("parquet") \
  .outputMode("append") \
  .option('path', 'test-3/data') \
  .option("checkpointLocation", "test-3/checkpoint") \
  .trigger(processingTime='20 seconds') \
  .start()
```

Output:

```
├── id=1
│   ├── part-00000-ed6ed5dd-b376-40a2-9920-d0cb36c7120f.c000.snappy.parquet
│   ├── part-00001-fa64e597-a4e1-4ac2-967f-5ea8aae96c13.c000.snappy.parquet
│   └── part-00002-0e0feab8-57d8-4bd2-a94f-0206ff90f16e.c000.snappy.parquet
├── id=2
│   ├── part-00000-c417dac5-271f-4356-b577-ff6c9f45792e.c000.snappy.parquet
│   ├── part-00001-7c90eb8a-986a-4602-a386-50f8d6d85e77.c000.snappy.parquet
│   └── part-00002-0e59e779-84e8-4fcf-ad62-ef3f4dbaccd5.c000.snappy.parquet
├── id=3
│   ├── part-00000-8a555649-1141-42fe-9cb5-0acf0efc5997.c000.snappy.parquet
│   ├── part-00001-ce4aaa50-e41b-4f5f-837c-661459b747b8.c000.snappy.parquet
│   └── part-00002-9f95261e-bd4c-4f1e-bce2-f8ab3b8b01ec.c000.snappy.parquet
```

You mentioned that you are using a `10-minute` batch so you should accordingly update you trigger interval as well. Right now it's `2 seconds` but it should be `trigger(processingTime='10 minutes')`(Refer `class ProcessingTime(Trigger)` [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/streaming.html) ). This could be why you are getting too many small files.

If you use `reaprtition(1)` with `10 minute batch` there will be a lot of shuffling of data and only one core(per `host, dt and h`) will end up writing all your data and you won't be able to use spark parallelism to it's extent. Also one more downside is bigger partitions than `128MB`. As you are not doing any aggregation in your query you should `decrease your batch size` and use `repartition(1)` such that you can have an acceptable partition size.

Comment: Can you please explain how to get folder structure in below format


├── id=1
│   ├── part-00000-ed6ed5dd-b376-40a2-9920-d0cb36c7120f.c000.snappy.parquet

Comment: @Feroz `partitionBy("id")` will create folders with `id=<value>`